# Do I have this idea of antiderivatives correct?

Tags: calculus

So is all it's saying that if there are two functions that have the same derivatives for every single $x$ in the interval, then $f(x) = g(x) + \alpha$, means that the second function is just the exact same as $f(x)$ except raised or lowered?

Comment: If by "raised or lowered", you mean that the graph of $g$ is the graph of $f$ translated up or down, yes, you seem to have a correct idea.

Comment: You should be able to prove your idea by a direct use of mean value theorem. Proving it without the use mean value theorem is hard and should convince you of the importance of mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the difference $f-g$ must then have zero derivative everywhere and therefore be constant. This means the graph of $f$ is the graph of $g$ shifted vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\int f(x)\ dx$ is a *family* of functions that only differ by a constant, which is typically denoted by $c$. This constant $c$ can be viewed as a shift vertically of the function.

The idea of a family of antiderivatives is easily shown by, say $f(x)=x^2+1$ and $g(x)=x^2-5$. While $f \ne g$, it is true that $f'=g'$. Likewise $\int 2x\ dx=x^2+c$, which contains $f$ and $g$.